# How can I control media volume from a 3-button in-line remote?

Tags: 2.2-froyo, volume-control, headset

I have the standard HTC RC-E160 headset with 3 buttons and a mic. I can use the button in the middle to pause and play music tracks, and I can use the buttons on each side to jump to next or previous track. Is there a way I can use these buttons to increase or decrease the volume? I am thinking maybe something like quickly pressing one of the buttons two times to increase the volume by one increment? Is something like this possible?

Maybe I need a Bluetooth headset? Or a wired headset with a 5 button remote control?

I am using MortPlayer Music as my primary music player and it has some options to set the button action for the headset but I see no options for volume control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a headset controller app from the playstore (e.g. [Jays](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.jays.headsetcontrol) or [Philips Headset](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.philips.cl.headset) or [HeadsetButton Controller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kober.headsetbutton)) to use the "middle button" for that. Might take a few tries to find the correct app (if one doesn't work fine, try another -- I did the same and finally found one working perfectly, see my [answer here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/38700/16575)). I'm not sure if they affect the other two buttons at all, or if you even could configure them -- but they allow me (having a headset with a single button) to perfom all the most necessary functions like play/pause, skip, vol+ and vol- with a single button.

Comment: My HTC headset control buttons have stopped working. I thought it was because of my recent installation of SuperNova ROM on the phone, and maybe some headphone background service or process not working properly, but it turned out that the cable was chewed up (from inside) at the point it enters the jack. I originally used my Sony headphones with this phone, but the left one got broken. Now I have used my original HTC headset that came with the phone and it only lasted about 5 months or so.

Comment: Well, this solution should work with your replacement headset (which you certainly have to buy now) as well :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into the a-Jays One+ and the companion app. I don't think it's for me. I don't like flat cables and also it's not very good for sports. The Philips ActionFit series with 3 buttons seems like a better option, and also the companion app seems to be very good.

Comment: I tried the Headset Button Controller app. It has a lot of options and I like that. But it interferes with my music app. I used MortPlayer Music during the test. This app has some headset control options already built in to it. Is there no dedicated option in Android that controls which apps get priority?... I couldn't find such option. If you have more than one music app they will interrupt each other. I also experienced some delay, like 2 to 3 seconds, after pressing a button to go to next track and then hearing the track.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to disable headset control in MortPlayer Music. But any such app should have this option, in my opinion, otherwise they will conflict with other such apps.

Comment: How do you get around this? You just install the music app you plan on using and no other apps? I will wait for the Sony SBH50, and then maybe get some extra pair of sports headphones to use with it. My research shows that a Bluetooth enabled controller is the only way you can take full control of music playback on Android (track control, volume, play, pause, stop). It needs to be a five button controller.

Comment: I don't know about mort player (never used it). But with some of those controler apps, you can configure which music app they shall use. I don't remember any conflict when having multiple music players installed; it always controled the one already running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, some of the apps are like that. As long as you stay within the app (having the app in the foreground) it's all cool. But some of the apps (or I should say all of them) allow you to have it running in the background and still play music, and some of them will automatically play a song when you plug in a headset or pause it when you unplug the headset. This can be cool sometimes. But for some reason I end up in the wrong music app when doing this. Or when I press the button the wrong player starts to play.

Comment: Is there nothing like "set default X app" where X stands for things like Music, Web, Video, etc. in Android? Like you have "standard programs" in Windows and "open with" et. al.? No such thing in Android? A central control panel where you can decide who does what? What button triggers what app, what action etc.?

Comment: I think this is all cumbersome, with these 3 button controllers. I liked the old 90's era Sony MD/CD Walkman idea much better, where dedicated, flashy controllers allowed you to do just about anything. Not only did they have Next/Previous/Volume/Play/Pause they also had dedicated Stop, Hold, Menu, backlit LCD, instant action, no delays and no gimmicks. They costed a bunch but they were much easier and effective than these iPhone/Android weird half-baked solutions where not even a 3-ring TRS jack is not the same across all brands.

Comment: Hell! You could even [control people](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ymNFyxvIdaM) with those things! :) That's control, right there!